# Why mpicxx is uble to compile cpp code includes boost library?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, openmpi

I am trying to compile a code in a Linux-based cluster with open PBS scheduler using the following command

> /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/open_mpi/bin/mpicxx -I/home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/ -I/home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/eigen-3.4.0/ -I /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/gsl/include/ -c test.cpp

But it is creating a long error list, and I am just adding last part of it

> /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:231:10: note:   ‘boost::math::policies::detail::raise_domain_error’  inline T
> raise_domain_error(
> ^ In file included from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:28:0,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/factorials.hpp:14,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp:14,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/bulirsch_stoer_dense_out.hpp:31,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp:45,
> from test.cpp:7: /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/powm1.hpp:47:60:
> error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
> return boost::math::policies::raise_domain_error(function, "For
> non-integral exponent, expected base > 0 but got %1%", x, pol);
> ^ In file included from
> /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:30:0,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/factorials.hpp:14,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp:14,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/bulirsch_stoer_dense_out.hpp:31,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp:45,
> from test.cpp:7: /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/lanczos.hpp:
> At global scope:
> /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/lanczos.hpp:91:48:
> error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token  struct lanczos6 :
> public std::integral_constant<int, 35>
> ^ /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/lanczos.hpp:91:48:
> error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
> /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/lanczos.hpp:91:48:
> error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token In file included from
> /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint/algebra/multi_array_algebra.hpp:22:0,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp:63,
> from test.cpp:7: /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/multi_array.hpp:25:30:
> error: expected ‘}’ before end of line  #  pragma GCC diagnostic push
> ^ /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/multi_array.hpp:25:30:
> error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
> /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/multi_array.hpp:25:30:
> error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
> /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/multi_array.hpp:25:30:
> error: expected declaration before end of line

What I have understood is that the error is due to the boost library.

On the other hand, I have compiled the same code in my local machine using the following command

> /home/debamalya/cpp_libraries/open_mpi/bin/mpicxx
> -I/home/debamalya/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/ -I/home/debamalya/cpp_libraries/eigen-3.4.0/ -I/home/debamalya/cpp_libraries/gsl/include/ -c test.cpp

and it compiles fine.

To resolve compatibility issue, I am using same version of boost library and open mpi in both machines. I have also compiled other cpp codes using the following command in the cluster

> /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/gcc-11.3.0/bin/g++
> -I/home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/ -I/home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/eigen-3.4.0/ -I/home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/gsl/include/ -c test.cpp

but that creates no problem.

I am very confused. Please help me to understand the problem and resolve the issue.

I am also attaching first few line of the error message

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/type_traits:35:0,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/math_fwd.hpp:28,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp:13,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/bulirsch_stoer_dense_out.hpp:31,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp:45,
> from test.cpp:7: /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This
> file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011
> standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled
> with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.  #error This
> file requires compiler and library support for the \   ^ In file
> included from
> /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp:11:0,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/math_fwd.hpp:29,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp:13,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/bulirsch_stoer_dense_out.hpp:31,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp:45,
> from test.cpp:7: /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:23:6:
> warning: #warning "The minimum language standard to use Boost.Math
> will be C++14 starting in July 2023 (Boost 1.82 release)" [-Wcpp]  #
> warning "The minimum language standard to use Boost.Math will be C++14
> starting in July 2023 (Boost 1.82 release)"
> ^ In file included from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/constants/constants.hpp:11:0,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/gamma.hpp:24,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/factorials.hpp:14,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp:14,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/bulirsch_stoer_dense_out.hpp:31,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp:45,
> from test.cpp:7: /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/tools/cxx03_warn.hpp:92:2:
> error: #error Support for C++03 has been removed. The minimum
> requirement for this library is fully compliant C++11.  #error Support
> for C++03 has been removed. The minimum requirement for this library
> is fully compliant C++11.   ^ In file included from
> /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp:11:0,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/math_fwd.hpp:29,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp:13,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/bulirsch_stoer_dense_out.hpp:31,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp:45,
> from test.cpp:7: /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:368:32:
> error: expected initializer before ‘noexcept’  #define
> BOOST_MATH_NOEXCEPT(T) noexcept(std::is_floating_point::value)
> ^ /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:470:62:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘BOOST_MATH_NOEXCEPT’  inline T max
> BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION(T a, T b, T c) BOOST_MATH_NOEXCEPT(T)
> ^ /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:368:32:
> error: expected initializer before ‘noexcept’  #define
> BOOST_MATH_NOEXCEPT(T) noexcept(std::is_floating_point::value)
> ^ /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:476:67:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘BOOST_MATH_NOEXCEPT’  inline T max
> BOOST_PREVENT_MACRO_SUBSTITUTION(T a, T b, T c, T d)
> BOOST_MATH_NOEXCEPT(T)
> ^ /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:368:32:
> error: expected initializer before ‘noexcept’  #define
> BOOST_MATH_NOEXCEPT(T) noexcept(std::is_floating_point::value)
> ^ /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:484:49:
> note: in expansion of macro ‘BOOST_MATH_NOEXCEPT’  void
> suppress_unused_variable_warning(const T&) BOOST_MATH_NOEXCEPT(T)
> ^ /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:493:11:
> error: ‘constexpr’ does not name a type
> static constexpr bool value = std::is_integral::value || (std::numeric_limits::is_specialized &&
> std::numeric_limits::is_integer);
> ^ /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:493:11:
> note: C++11 ‘constexpr’ only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
> In file included from
> /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/detail/round_fwd.hpp:12:0,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/math_fwd.hpp:29,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp:13,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/bulirsch_stoer_dense_out.hpp:31,
> from /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/numeric/odeint.hpp:45,
> from test.cpp:7: /home/debamalya/cpp/cpp_libraries/boost_1_81_0/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp:57:15:
> error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘type’
> using type = typename std::conditionalstd::is_integral<T::value, double, T>::type;

Comment: Maybe it's a problem of the compiler version. What does ```mpicxx --version``` give on both machines?
Also, please rather include the *first* part of the error messages.

Comment: Yes, the problem is regarding the g++ compiler version which has been used to install openmpi. Some versions of g++ are not compatible with the Boost cpp library.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to link a library (e.g. netcdf) then you have to linked with -l followed by the name of the library; use the something like:

`> mpicxx -lnetcdf test.cpp`

If you need to specify the location of that library then you need to use a capital -L followed by the full path to the library location:

`> mpicxx -L/home/user/mylibraries/netcdf4 -lnetcdf test.cpp`

In you case, you are using -l for the path and no specification of which library to link. Obviously this is a simplified example, it might be needed to first compile the object file text.o and then create the executable, but that depends on your implementation. ;)